# asp.net boilerplate odata count

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, odata, aspnetboilerplate

I'm developing asp.net core boilerplate application with odata support. I'm trying to enable $count parametr:

```
app.UseOData(builder =>
            {
                builder.EntitySet<Message>("Messages").EntityType.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().Page().Count();//.Expand().Filter().OrderBy().Page();
            });
```

and request is:

```
/odata/Messages?%24count=true&%24filter=indexof(tolower(Guid)%2C+%27a3eee6ec-d232-42f7-93cc-fd6062fb39b6%27)+gt+-1
```

but response has no count:

```
{
"result": [
{
"guid": "a3eee6ec-d232-42f7-93cc-fd6062fb39b6",
"id": 140
}
],
"targetUrl": null,
"success": true,
"error": null,
"unAuthorizedRequest": false,
"__abp": true
}
```

How to add **count** to response with boilerblate odata?

p.s.

```
<ItemGroup>

    <PackageReference Include="Abp.AspNetCore.OData" Version="3.8.2" /> 
    <PackageReference Include="Abp.AspNetCore.SignalR" Version="3.7.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Abp.AspNetCore" Version="3.8.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData" Version="7.0.1" />    

    ... 

  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: /odata/Messages/$count

Comment: thks, that was very helpful. But i understand, that my question wasnt correct, so i change it

Comment: /odata/Messages?$count=true&$filter=

Comment: that's the problem - response does not contain count

Comment: Could not repro. Create a repro project on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

for getting count in the result the url should be:

```
/odata/message?$count=true
```